# Enable textboxes and button after form submittal ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to enable the update button after form submittal. Here's my code:

**VIEW:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessTech", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.techNo, new { @class = "form-control maintain-text", placeholder = "Technician No..." })

    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" id="search" name="SubmitButton" value="search" class="btn btn-default">                        
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    </button>
    </span>

    <td>First Name :</td>
    <td class="display-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstName, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:380px;", disabled = "disabled" })</td>

    <td>Last Name :</td>
    <td class="display-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.lastName, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:380px;", disabled = "disabled" })</td>

    <button name="SubmitButton" value="update" id="update" type="submit" style = "float:right;margin-right:10px; border-radius:5px;" class="btn btn-default" disabled><i class='fa fa-edit fa-fw'></i>Update</button>   
}
```

The **update button**, **firstname** & **lastname** textboxes has a **'disabled'** attribute. 
After searching the technician number, the form will be updated with the firstname & lastname values that corresponds to the tech number.

Now I want to remove the disabled attribute of the update button, firstname and lastname so that it can be edited and updated. What's the best way to do this?

I tried this:

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").click(function () {               
        $("#update,#firstName,#lastName").removeAttr("disabled");              
    });            
});
```

It enables the elements while the form is submitting but as soon as the form is submitted the page reloads with the values already in the textboxes and disables back the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified my code based on Maneesh's answer and here's what I've come up:

**MODEL:**

```
public bool setEnable { get; set; }
public IndexModel() { setEnable = false; } //constructor
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    return View(new IndexModel());                                 
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessTech(string SubmitButton)
{   
    IndexModel _oTechModel = new IndexModel();          

    switch (SubmitButton)
    {       
        case "search": //search technician
            {               
                _oTechModel.setEnable = true;
            }
            break;  
    }    
    return View("Index", _oTechModel);         
}
```

**VIEW:**

```
@model Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel
@{    
    ViewBag.Title = "Technician";
    if(Model.setEnable==true)
    {
        ViewBag.disableUpdate = "";
    }
    else{
        ViewBag.disableUpdate = "disabled";
    }
}

//HTML codes goes here..
```

Answer (score 1):

When you post the form to the controller you can return a value in the model to the view, which will determine if the button will be disabled or enabled, or you can also use @Viewbag.disableUpdate so that after post the button renders correctly

```
<button name="SubmitButton" value="update" id="update" type="submit"  class="btn btn-default" @ViewBag.disableUpdate ><i class='fa fa-edit fa-fw'></i>Update</button>
```

From the controller pass @ViewBag.disableUpdate="" // to make it enable

and @ViewBag.disableUpdate="disable"; // to make it enabled

Comment: The code you posted won't work. *"The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value"* [(1)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) So the element will always be disabled.

Comment: Hi, I got compilation error. It says "The name 'Viewbag' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: Try `ViewBag`. Case sensitive.